# How can I acess a NFS server from outside of the local network

Tags: linux, nfs

I have an NFS server and I want to be able to use it places other than just home. How (if possible) can I access it from other places? Would I just simply port forward the port NFS is using?

Comment: Have you considered using sshfs or something similar?

Comment: There's multiple ways of achieving this, you are correct, you could port-forward. The most common way would be to use a VPN, if you decide to go with this route, look into OpenVPN (https://openvpn.net/). @barrycarters idea is also another way you could do this, all depends on how secure you want your NFS server to be.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just port-forwarding, but I think I will look into both using a VPN and sshfs for this job later